# Django Sqlite Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

Ok, when I use inspectdb on an existing SQLite database the foreign key is generated as a `ml_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ML_ID', blank=False, null=False)`

Even though it is in this form, is it still used as a foreign key by Django. If not, how to set this to an existing foreign key?

I ask this because it states:

> 7.Foreign-key detection only works with PostgreSQL and with certain types of MySQL tables. In other cases, foreign-key fields will be generated as IntegerField`s, assuming the foreign-key column was an`INT column.

at this [link](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the generated model code.

```
ml = models.ForeignKey('ml_model', db_column='ML_ID', blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel Roseman!!!. That was simple and that is all I needed. I am loving Django more and more everyday.